# Objective-C (iOS) replace all occurrences of Wildcard in a string with the alphabet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, replace, wildcard

First of all, this is not homework!  :)

Say I have an NSString: `"the?or?"`  For each wildcard i want the string to come back with at least 26 (not including 'ñ' and 'ng' that seem to have been added by some countries like the Phillipines).  So a word with 2 `?` would give me 26^2 (i think) results.

I want it to return an NSArray of the following:

```
theaora
theaorb
theaorc
...
thezora
thezorb
thezorc
...
thezorx
thezory
thezorz
```

Since this is recursion (I am assuming) I am having issues...

I am working on this:

```
NSArray *countOfWildCardArray = [wordToSearch componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];
        int countOfWildCard = [countOfWildCardArray count] - 1;
        if (countOfWildCard > 0)
        {
            for ( NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfWildCard; i++) 
            {
                NSLog(@"Looking for wildcard #%i",i);
                for(char a = 'a'; a <= 'z'; a++)
                {   
                    NSString *tempStringA = [NSString stringWithString:wordToSearchFor];

                ......
                }
            }
        }
```

and then I am lost.  I actually don't think I am on the right track.  Like I said, recursion bothers me a lot :)

Does anyone have an idea of what do do?

So, after having received a few questions I will just state that this issue has to do with letting the user know how many anagrams I can make from those resulting words.  I have a fast way of making the anagrams for the word list and am simply looking to create the word list that the anagrams are to be made from.  I am sure there is a better way than the above method.  What I am asking for is some help finding the best way of creating the array.

Comment: Why do you want this? If you're going to cycle through the results and try to match them against a string, then this has to be the least efficient implementation of glob I've heard of.

Comment: @kevinballard I have now answered your question in the last paragraph of the posting.  thanks!

Comment: Your new nightmare: `??????????`. Have fun generating 1.5 TB of strings.

Comment: I know.  There is a limit of around 6 characters... BUT I understand the danger.

Comment: If you just need to tell the user how many you can generate, why are you actually generating them? Just count the number of `"?"` and raise 26 to that power.

Comment: Because the list is shown to the user to scan.  @kevinballard, I know you are trying to get me to do this a different way.  But, trust me, I want the list of possible words.  I just want the best/fastest way of generating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSArray *wildCardArray;
NSArray *countOfWildCardArray = [wordToSearch componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];
        int countOfWildCard = [countOfWildCardArray count] - 1;
        if (countOfWildCard > 0)
        {
            for(char a = 'a'; a <= 'z'; a++)
             { 
                for(char b = 'a'; b <= 'z'; b++)
                {  
                     NSString *tempStringA=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%c%@%c",[countOfWildCardArray objectAtIndex:0],a,[countOfWildCardArray objectAtIndex:1],b];
                     [wildCardArray addObject:tempStringA];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: ummm.  not to look a gift horse in the mouth :)  but `stringByAppendingFormat` is followed by an incomplete format.  Did you mean `@"%@%c"`, ...  Also, why did you not use `char b` or `char a`?  arent they required to complete the substitution?  thanks for the help tho.  Can you elucidate a bit more?  :)

Comment: First thing:  Thanks for helping!  Now, one last thing!  I promise.  The 2 `?`'s were an example.  This replace turns `the?or?` into theaory, theaorz, thebora, theborb, etc... but it also turns `the?or` into the same listing.  In other words, how do i alter it to change out ONLY the exact number of `?` that the word contains.  ie: the ending word would have the same number of replaced characters as the starting word.  This would include having 4 `?`'s, or 5 `?`'s, etc.

Comment: stringByAppendingFormat ... that was a messup (typing issue on my part)... sorry.

Comment: @Jann u want to just replace ? with characters?

Comment: I want to replace each ? with A-Z.  So if there was one ? in the string, i would get back 26 strings in an array.  if 2, i would get back 26^2 nsstrings in an array.  get it?

Comment: yup.. i will try it and post it asap